# Are iOS device UDIDs case sensitive?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

This is about adding devices to the provisioning portal for ad-hoc testing.  A client sent me a UDID with upper-case characters which I foolishly added without checking.  Wireless deployment isn't working and I'm wondering whether this could be the cause, but I would like to check first before using up one of my 100 allocations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, *UDIDs* are case sensitive.
You can go through all characters and turn them to a lower case character, if it's not a number.

Comment: I have created an both central and peripheral tested. Central UUID is capital and peripheral UUId is small letters. but, I can communicate.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct that iTunes lists the UDID in uppercase.

Be aware that in the 'Member center' you'll have to register the UDID in lowercase, otherwise the device will not be recognised. So copy-paste is not working for this!

When the device is recognized the model and type will be listed. When that is not the case the device will not be working in AdHoc mode.