# How to solve my UDID issue in Apple Developer Portal?

Tags: ios, iphone, udid

For my iOS application, I mistakenly added UDID with uppercase letters in apple developer portal. When i create build and try to install into device that was always shows unable to download app alert message.

Now i want remove or modify UDID which is already registered in developer portal But i am unable to do as apple did not give permission to remove or modify.

So what should i do to run my app in same UDID device. As i found my UDID problem with reference of this link "[Are iOS device UDIDs case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864379/are-ios-device-udids-case-sensitive)".

Comment: You have to add new udid and create new profile. You can't delete register udid until you renew your account.

Comment: just add as the new user when ever you  add the new UDID.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have only one option to run code to your device. Add one more time UDID correctly and then generate build.

Comment: I tried, but it always shows UDID already exist message. I am unable add one more time.:(

Comment: Then you need to contact Apple Developer Support so they can solve your problem. Because you need to add one more UDID. If they are not allowing then you can solve it without help from support.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add any UDID in developer account. Apple does not allow delete it. you can only disable that UDID. When your account get renew apple will ask you to reset the UDID list. Only that time you can remove that UDID from the list.

If you accidentally added wrong UDID. or if you want to add the same UDID in lower case then you can add new device. Apple allow you to add the same UDID in different case.

Comment: no luck. I am unable add new device with same UDID with lowercase.